# Split a list of values based on a value into a list using Java

Tags: java, list, algorithm, arraylist

Consider a list of long values `[1,2,3,4,2,3,6,3,7,3]`. I need to implement java program to split the list based on value. Let say `value = 3`. whenever I find `value = 3`. I need to split the list in such a way `[[1,2] ,[3],[4,2],[3],[6],[3],[7],[3]]`.

I wrote the below code to implement the problem statement:

```
    public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      list.add(1);
      list.add(2);
      list.add(3);
      list.add(4);
      list.add(2);
      list.add(3);
      list.add(6);
      list.add(3);
      list.add(7);
      System.out.println(list);

      int val = 3;
      List<List<Integer>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i : list) {
          if (i != val) {
              tempList.add(i);
          } else {
              finalList.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
              finalList.add(Arrays.asList(i));
              tempList.clear();
          }
      }

        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}
```

**Output:** `[[1, 2], [3], [4, 2], [3], [6], [3]]`

**Expected Output :** `[[1,2] ,[3],[4,2],[3],[6],[3],[7]]`

Last Number [7] is not getting added to the finalList. Any suggestion!

Comment: First of all, you are not adding these values `[1,2,3,4,2,3,6,3,7,3]` to the list. Please keep your input and the input in the code consistent.

Comment: After your for loop, temp list contains 7. So you have to add here to final list too.

Answer (score 0):

The prob is that you add the whole starting list in your array,

Instead you need to keep other array in mind so you can push this one when you come accross a 3.

```java
List<Integer> list_i_want_to_push = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){
              list_i_want_to_push.add(list.get(i));

              if(val == list.get(i)){
                  list_i_want_to_push.remove(i);
                  finalList.add(list_i_want_to_push);
                  finalList.add(Arrays.asList(val));
                  list_i_want_to_push = []; //empty your array
              }

             }
             System.out.println(finalList);
```

Comment: You code won't compile. It is `List<Integer>`, not `List<integer>`. Side note: `list_i_want_to_push` this is not java style. `Arrays.asList(val)` returns a fixed list, no modifications can be made to that in future if required.

Comment: @HarshalParekh, ow damn! didn't know the second part of your comment!! Thx mate, fixed type!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want but I had to make some assumptions.

- If adjacent split numbers occur, simply put each of them in their own list and add to final list.
- Assume that the list can start and/or end with one or more split numbers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitListOnValue {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3,3,2,3,4,2,3,3,3,6,6,6,3,7,3,3));
        System.out.println(list);

        int splitVal = 3;
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int item = list.get(i);
            if (item == splitVal) {
                // add both list and singleton list if temp not empty
                // other wise just add singletone list
                if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
                    finalList.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
                }
                finalList.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(splitVal)));
                // clear temp list and restart process
                temp.clear();
                continue;
            } 
            // still accumulating
            temp.add(item);
        }
        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[[3], [3], [2], [3], [4, 2], [3], [3], [3], [6, 6, 6], [3], [7], [3], [3]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The number you want to split by
    int delimiter = 3;
    List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 10, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4);

    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new ArrayList<>()); // Add a list so that we have something to work with

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        // Get the next value in the list
        int val = input.get(i);

        // If the current value equals the one we want to split by...
        if (val == delimiter) {
            //... add a new list containing only the delimiter...
            result.add(Arrays.asList(delimiter));

            //... and add a new list so the other values will be added correctly
            result.add(new ArrayList<>());
        } else // if this is just a random number, add it to the last list
            result.get(result.size() - 1).add(val);
    }

    // If the last number in your input is equal to the delimiter, there will be an empty
    // list at the end, which can be prevented this way
    if (result.get(result.size() - 1).size() == 0)
        result.remove(result.size() - 1);

}
```

Comment: Please add some context around your answer and don't just post the code.

Comment: On a side note, if you have taken time to write the answer, please also take some time to post a complete solution; do not leave `// your list` and add a sample list there.

Comment: Also, keep your variable names consistent with the variable names in the question. This could only be a part of OP's code.

Comment: There is an empty `[]` in the `result`.

Comment: @HarshalParekh You're right, I added some comments and am going to fix that empty `[]`. I will however use variable names that I'm most comfortable with, because if I'm going to post a solution for OP here, the least they can do is change the variable name's themselves.